# Windows 8 Boot process in EFI

Tags: windows-8, efi, bcd, bootmgr

I was trying to add Debian 7 boot entry to Windows boot menu using easyBCD. I accidentally deleted the Window 8 entry from the list now I get a `BCD error` when trying to boot. `Error code 0x000098`

How can I edit the BCD store from outside. I tried BCDedit and rebuildbcd from repair which shows an error, can't identify the specified drive

Where is the BCD file located in the ESP partition?
I can find one in `\EFI\BOOT\Microsoft\Boot` and one in `\Boot`

Another thing, I read somewhere the Windows boot manager is bootmgfw.efi. I can't find the specified file in `\EFI\BOOT\Microsoft\Boot`, instead there is a bootmgr.efi. Is it the same file?

When I tried `efibootmgr -v` from Linux it shows:

`BootOrder: 0003,2001,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0005,0006,0007,0004
Boot0000* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,276800,1f4000,336bcd4b-7976-44d9-b1e3-fec14c4abfed)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0001* EFI USB Device (JetFlashTranscend 4GB)    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1d,0)USB(0,0)USB(0,0)HD(1,20,78bfe0,c3072e18)RC
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,89514f5b-b782-470e-aff3-ed5cdede527c)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0004* Network Boot: Realtek PXE B01 D00 BIOS(80,0,95)........................&..............................................
Boot0005* SATA HDD    : ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB              BIOS(2,500,da)................-...........A..........................................
Boot0006* SATA ODD    : HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GU70N               BIOS(3,500,1f)................-...........A......#...................................
Boot0007* USB HDD     : JetFlashTranscend 4GB       BIOS(2,500,64).......................................................................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC`

Comment: Try running the Automatic Repair, It automatically fixes most of boot issues. And That'll also work in your case.

And most of the time it ends up with an error, Reboot to see if the boot is fixed.

Comment: The Windows boot loader is indeed `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`, not `bootmgr.efi`. If it's missing, then that's the problem (or at least part of it). Booting a Windows recovery tool and using its automatic recovery option *should* restore this file.